# Yodlee REST updateCredentialsForItem1 always return error

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to submit updated credentials using 'updateCredentialsForItem1' (via REST), but all the time I got this response from server:

`detailedMessage = "Technical Difficulty Processing Request";
    errorOccurred = true;
    exceptionType = "Unknown Exception Occurred";
    referenceCode = "_e48947fd-466a-4c24-a6e8-5bbac700857a";`

But in the same time 'addItemForContentService1' which have same set of params work well with the same arguments (except itemId which is replaced with contentServiceId for 'addItemForContentService1').

Here is the arguments I am passing to 'updateCredentialsForItem1':

`cobSessionToken = "01292015_0:85facdd62d5ba2da1d24067cb901ffdd347c0e7432f1e3fe9586df37433806cbbff7e2822fa98ce1949851367c06f81b88971fb6835659e70ce28a2800ec1a2c";
    "credentialFields.enclosedType" = "com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle";
    "credentialFields[0].displayName" = Catalog;
    "credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName" = "IF_LOGIN";
    "credentialFields[0].helpText" = 146590;
    "credentialFields[0].isEditable" = true;
    "credentialFields[0].maxlength" = 40;
    "credentialFields[0].name" = LOGIN;
    "credentialFields[0].size" = 20;
    "credentialFields[0].value" = "sbMempavel1.BankCaptcha1";
    "credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier" = LOGIN;
    "credentialFields[0].valueMask" = "LOGIN_FIELD";
    "credentialFields[1].displayName" = Password;
    "credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName" = "IF_PASSWORD";
    "credentialFields[1].helpText" = 146591;
    "credentialFields[1].isEditable" = true;
    "credentialFields[1].maxlength" = 40;
    "credentialFields[1].name" = PASSWORD;
    "credentialFields[1].size" = 20;
    "credentialFields[1].value" = BankCaptcha1;
    "credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier" = PASSWORD;
    "credentialFields[1].valueMask" = "LOGIN_FIELD";
    itemId = 13234909;
    shareCredentialsWithinSite = false;
    startRefreshItemOnAddition = false;
    userSessionToken = "01292015_0:41e09dfe0aae74c49eef4b144720b901275c57ed2937462f4da4c0cf059fc5d0eb1e27ad2e3f418d90eeefa3d8862f88905e7ca9fea001ae6a3c7908538e479c";`

Here is url encoded string that passed as POST body:

`credentialFields%5B1%5D.valueIdentifier=PASSWORD&itemId=13234909&cobSessionToken=01292015_0:d2ecdeda0dafcada784a8f9bf61561c667d427de6de7f01a6016e5135bf0f97b2210734eafead3e79c14e40b7931ba7dcc738cbfcabfdeacdeea183f89baeeda&credentialFields.enclosedType=com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle&userSessionToken=01292015_0:9e54be83b540f55b795e18680d93d61d8f88ee26061044b3bddec78057fa3bceadc8e9e57c3394594fc8495843591ada9e788876daa8df0648dc8b5f8f8bf830&credentialFields%5B0%5D.value=sbMempavel1.BankCaptcha1&startRefreshItemOnAddition=false&credentialFields%5B1%5D.isEditable=true&credentialFields%5B0%5D.isEditable=true&credentialFields%5B0%5D.valueMask=LOGIN_FIELD&credentialFields%5B1%5D.fieldType.typeName=IF_PASSWORD&credentialFields%5B0%5D.valueIdentifier=LOGIN&credentialFields%5B0%5D.fieldType.typeName=IF_LOGIN&credentialFields%5B1%5D.name=PASSWORD&credentialFields%5B0%5D.helpText=146590&credentialFields%5B1%5D.size=20&credentialFields%5B0%5D.displayName=Catalog&credentialFields%5B1%5D.valueMask=LOGIN_FIELD&credentialFields%5B1%5D.helpText=146591&credentialFields%5B0%5D.maxlength=40&credentialFields%5B1%5D.value=BankCaptcha1&credentialFields%5B0%5D.name=LOGIN&credentialFields%5B0%5D.size=20&credentialFields%5B1%5D.maxlength=40&credentialFields%5B1%5D.displayName=Password`

Any ideas why 'updateCredentialsForItem1' always produce the this error and what does it mean?
Also subquestion - how can I detect situation when I need to use 'updateCredentialsForItem1'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing one extra parameter which is not for [updateCredentialsForItem1](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/updateCredentialsForItem1)

You should not be passing  "shareCredentialsWithinSite" parameter. Make the change and try using the API again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but unfortunately removing "shareCredentialsWithinSite" parameter does not help. Still the same error is returned by Yodlee server. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also I have added url encoded string of parameters that is passed as POST body to initial question. Maybe this will help to clarify the problem.